# This Search Collapsible Tree code doesn't work when I run it on my PC?

Tags: html, node.js, d3.js

I found this interesting d3 Search Collapsible Tree here https://bl.ocks.org/jjzieve/a743242f46321491a950 and when I tried to run it on my machine locally it didn't work. I do realize the fact that I just started diving into coding world and have no previous experience but I wish if someone can help me taking a look at the way that I put the code from the source.

Is that how to do it? Why it doesn't work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<style>
    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node circle {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .found {
        fill: #ff4136;
        stroke: #ff4136;
    }
    .node text {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    /*Just to ensure the select2 box is "glued" to the top*/
    .search {
      width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.css"></link>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<!-- This will be attached to select2, only static element on the page -->
<div id="search"></div>

<!-- Main -->
<script type="text/javascript">




{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "animate",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
    {
     "name": "interpolate",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
      {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
      {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
      {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
      {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
      {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "data",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "converters",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
      {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
      {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
      {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
      {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
    {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
    {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
    {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
    {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
    {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "display",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
    {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
    {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
    {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "flex",
   "children": [
    {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "physics",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
    {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
    {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
    {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
    {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
    {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
    {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
    {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "query",
   "children": [
    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
    {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
    {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
    {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
    {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
    {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
    {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
    {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
    {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
    {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
    {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
    {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
    {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
    {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
    {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
    {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
    {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
    {
     "name": "methods",
     "children": [
      {"name": "add", "size": 593},
      {"name": "and", "size": 330},
      {"name": "average", "size": 287},
      {"name": "count", "size": 277},
      {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
      {"name": "div", "size": 595},
      {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
      {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
      {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
      {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
      {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
      {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
      {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
      {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
      {"name": "max", "size": 283},
      {"name": "min", "size": 283},
      {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
      {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
      {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
      {"name": "not", "size": 386},
      {"name": "or", "size": 323},
      {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
      {"name": "range", "size": 772},
      {"name": "select", "size": 296},
      {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
      {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
      {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
      {"name": "update", "size": 307},
      {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
      {"name": "where", "size": 299},
      {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
      {"name": "_", "size": 264}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
    {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
    {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
    {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
    {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
    {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
    {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
    {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
    {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
    {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "scale",
   "children": [
    {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
    {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
    {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
    {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
    {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
    {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
    {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
    {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
    {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
    {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "util",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
    {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
    {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
    {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
    {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
    {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
    {
     "name": "heap",
     "children": [
      {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
      {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
    {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
    {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
    {
     "name": "math",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
      {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
      {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
    {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
    {
     "name": "palette",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
      {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
      {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
      {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
    {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
    {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
    {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
    {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "vis",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "axis",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
      {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
      {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
      {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
      {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "controls",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
      {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
      {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
      {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
      {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
      {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
      {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
      {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
      {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
      {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
      {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "data",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
      {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
      {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
      {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
      {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
      {
       "name": "render",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
      {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
      {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "events",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "legend",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
      {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
      {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "operator",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "distortion",
       "children": [
        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "encoder",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "filter",
       "children": [
        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
      {
       "name": "label",
       "children": [
        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "layout",
       "children": [
        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
      {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
      {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
      {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
      {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
   ]
  }
 ]
}




    //basically a way to get the path to an object
    function searchTree(obj,search,path){
        if(obj.name === search){ //if search is found return, add the object to the path and return it
            path.push(obj);
            return path;
        }
        else if(obj.children || obj._children){ //if children are collapsed d3 object will have them instantiated as _children
            var children = (obj.children) ? obj.children : obj._children;
            for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
                path.push(obj);// we assume this path is the right one
                var found = searchTree(children[i],search,path);
                if(found){// we were right, this should return the bubbled-up path from the first if statement
                    return found;
                }
                else{//we were wrong, remove this parent from the path and continue iterating
                    path.pop();
                }
            }
        }
        else{//not the right object, return false so it will continue to iterate in the loop
            return false;
        }
    }

    function extract_select2_data(node,leaves,index){
            if (node.children){
                for(var i = 0;i<node.children.length;i++){
                    index = extract_select2_data(node.children[i],leaves,index)[0];
                }
            }
            else {
                leaves.push({id:++index,text:node.name});
            }
            return [index,leaves];
    }

    var div = d3.select("body")
        .append("div") // declare the tooltip div
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 0);

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
        width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
        height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var i = 0,
        duration = 750,
        root,
        select2_data;

    var diameter = 960;

    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .size([height, width]);

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //recursively collapse children
    function collapse(d) {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d._children.forEach(collapse);
            d.children = null;
        }
    }

    // Toggle children on click.
    function click(d) {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
        }
        else{
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
    }

    function openPaths(paths){
        for(var i =0;i<paths.length;i++){
            if(paths[i].id !== "1"){//i.e. not root
                paths[i].class = 'found';
                if(paths[i]._children){ //if children are hidden: open them, otherwise: don't do anything
                    paths[i].children = paths[i]._children;
                    paths[i]._children = null;
                }
                update(paths[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    d3.json("flare.json", function(error,values){
        root = values;
        select2_data = extract_select2_data(values,[],0)[1];//I know, not the prettiest...
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;
        root.children.forEach(collapse);
        update(root);
        //init search box
        $("#search").select2({
            data: select2_data,
            containerCssClass: "search"
        });
    });
    //attach search box listener
    $("#search").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
        var paths = searchTree(root,e.object.text,[]);
        if(typeof(paths) !== "undefined"){
            openPaths(paths);
        }
        else{
            alert(e.object.text+" not found!");
        }
    })

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

    function update(source) {
        // Compute the new tree layout.
        var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

        // Normalize for fixed-depth.
        nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

        // Update the nodesâ€¦
        var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

        // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
        .on("click", click);

        nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 1e-6)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

        nodeEnter.append("text")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

        // Transition nodes to their new position.
        var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

        nodeUpdate.select("circle")
            .attr("r", 4.5)
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                if(d.class === "found"){
                    return "#ff4136"; //red
                }
                else if(d._children){
                    return "lightsteelblue";
                }
                else{
                    return "#fff";
                }
            })
            .style("stroke", function(d) {
                if(d.class === "found"){
                    return "#ff4136"; //red
                }
        });

        nodeUpdate.select("text")
            .style("fill-opacity", 1);

        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
        var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
            .remove();

        nodeExit.select("circle")
            .attr("r", 1e-6);

        nodeExit.select("text")
            .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

        // Update the linksâ€¦
        var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
            .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

        // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
        link.enter().insert("path", "g")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
            });

        // Transition links to their new position.
        link.transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("d", diagonal)
            .style("stroke",function(d){
                if(d.target.class==="found"){
                    return "#ff4136";
                }
            });

        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
        link.exit().transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
            })
            .remove();

        // Stash the old positions for transition.
        nodes.forEach(function(d) {
            d.x0 = d.x;
            d.y0 = d.y;
          });
    }


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If that's the exact content that you're trying to run, you're missing some required HTML tags, like `body`.

Comment: @TiesonT. I just fixed it and still not working.

Comment: That's still not a valid HTML page. You might want to start with the basics: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case you're still interested in this, you can achieve the same effect only using HTML.
**Working Example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <style>
        .node {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .node circle {
            fill: #fff;
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .found {
            fill: #ff4136;
            stroke: #ff4136;
        }
        .node text {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #ccc;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
        /*Just to ensure the select2 box is "glued" to the top*/
        .search {
          width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="search"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- This will be attached to select2, only static element on the page -->


    <!-- Main -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //basically a way to get the path to an object
        function searchTree(obj,search,path){
            if(obj.name === search){ //if search is found return, add the object to the path and return it
                path.push(obj);
                return path;
            }
            else if(obj.children || obj._children){ //if children are collapsed d3 object will have them instantiated as _children
                var children = (obj.children) ? obj.children : obj._children;
                for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
                    path.push(obj);// we assume this path is the right one
                    var found = searchTree(children[i],search,path);
                    if(found){// we were right, this should return the bubbled-up path from the first if statement
                        return found;
                    }
                    else{//we were wrong, remove this parent from the path and continue iterating
                        path.pop();
                    }
                }
            }
            else{//not the right object, return false so it will continue to iterate in the loop
                return false;
            }
        }

        function extract_select2_data(node,leaves,index){
                if (node.children){
                    for(var i = 0;i<node.children.length;i++){
                        index = extract_select2_data(node.children[i],leaves,index)[0];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    leaves.push({id:++index,text:node.name});
                }
                return [index,leaves];
        }

        var div = d3.select("body")
            .append("div") // declare the tooltip div
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0);

        var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
            width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
            height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var i = 0,
            duration = 750,
            root,
            select2_data;

        var diameter = 960;

        var tree = d3.layout.tree()
            .size([height, width]);

        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        //recursively collapse children
        function collapse(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d._children.forEach(collapse);
                d.children = null;
            }
        }

        // Toggle children on click.
        function click(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            }
            else{
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
            update(d);
        }

        function openPaths(paths){
            for(var i =0;i<paths.length;i++){
                if(paths[i].id !== "1"){//i.e. not root
                    paths[i].class = 'found';
                    if(paths[i]._children){ //if children are hidden: open them, otherwise: don't do anything
                        paths[i].children = paths[i]._children;
                        paths[i]._children = null;
                    }
                    update(paths[i]);
                }
            }
        }


            values = {"name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "animate",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
    {
     "name": "interpolate",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
      {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
      {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
      {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
      {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
      {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "data",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "converters",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
      {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
      {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
      {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
      {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
    {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
    {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
    {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
    {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
    {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "display",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
    {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
    {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
    {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "flex",
   "children": [
    {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "physics",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
    {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
    {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
    {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
    {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
    {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
    {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
    {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "query",
   "children": [
    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
    {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
    {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
    {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
    {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
    {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
    {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
    {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
    {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
    {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
    {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
    {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
    {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
    {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
    {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
    {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
    {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
    {
     "name": "methods",
     "children": [
      {"name": "add", "size": 593},
      {"name": "and", "size": 330},
      {"name": "average", "size": 287},
      {"name": "count", "size": 277},
      {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
      {"name": "div", "size": 595},
      {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
      {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
      {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
      {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
      {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
      {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
      {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
      {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
      {"name": "max", "size": 283},
      {"name": "min", "size": 283},
      {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
      {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
      {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
      {"name": "not", "size": 386},
      {"name": "or", "size": 323},
      {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
      {"name": "range", "size": 772},
      {"name": "select", "size": 296},
      {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
      {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
      {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
      {"name": "update", "size": 307},
      {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
      {"name": "where", "size": 299},
      {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
      {"name": "_", "size": 264}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
    {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
    {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
    {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
    {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
    {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
    {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
    {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
    {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
    {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "scale",
   "children": [
    {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
    {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
    {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
    {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
    {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
    {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
    {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
    {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
    {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
    {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "util",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
    {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
    {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
    {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
    {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
    {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
    {
     "name": "heap",
     "children": [
      {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
      {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
    {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
    {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
    {
     "name": "math",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
      {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
      {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
    {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
    {
     "name": "palette",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
      {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
      {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
      {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
    {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
    {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
    {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
    {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "vis",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "axis",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
      {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
      {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
      {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
      {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "controls",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
      {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
      {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
      {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
      {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
      {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
      {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
      {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
      {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
      {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
      {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "data",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
      {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
      {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
      {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
      {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
      {
       "name": "render",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
      {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
      {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "events",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "legend",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
      {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
      {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "operator",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "distortion",
       "children": [
        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "encoder",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "filter",
       "children": [
        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
      {
       "name": "label",
       "children": [
        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "layout",
       "children": [
        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
      {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
      {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
      {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
      {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
   ]
  }
 ]
};
        root = values;
            select2_data = extract_select2_data(values,[],0)[1];//I know, not the prettiest...
            root.x0 = height / 2;
            root.y0 = 0;
            root.children.forEach(collapse);
            update(root);
            //init search box
            $("#search").select2({
                data: select2_data,
                containerCssClass: "search"
            });
        //attach search box listener
        $("#search").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
            var paths = searchTree(root,e.object.text,[]);
            if(typeof(paths) !== "undefined"){
                openPaths(paths);
            }
            else{
                alert(e.object.text+" not found!");
            }
        })

        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

        function update(source) {
            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                links = tree.links(nodes);

            // Normalize for fixed-depth.
            nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                d.y = d.depth * 180;
            });

            // Update the nodesâ€¦
            var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(nodes, function (d) {
                    return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                });

            // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                })
                .on("click", click);

            nodeEnter.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 1e-6)
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                });

            nodeEnter.append("text")
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
                })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                })
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.name;
                })
                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

            // Transition nodes to their new position.
            var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                });

            nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                .attr("r", 4.5)
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    if (d.class === "found") {
                        return "#ff4136"; //red
                    } else if (d._children) {
                        return "lightsteelblue";
                    } else {
                        return "#fff";
                    }
                })
                .style("stroke", function (d) {
                    if (d.class === "found") {
                        return "#ff4136"; //red
                    }
                });

            nodeUpdate.select("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);

            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                })
                .remove();

            nodeExit.select("circle")
                .attr("r", 1e-6);

            nodeExit.select("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

            // Update the linksâ€¦
            var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                .data(links, function (d) {
                    return d.target.id;
                });

            // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
            link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", function (d) {
                    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                });

            // Transition links to their new position.
            link.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("d", diagonal)
                .style("stroke", function (d) {
                    if (d.target.class === "found") {
                        return "#ff4136";
                    }
                });

            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            link.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("d", function (d) {
                    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                })
                .remove();

            // Stash the old positions for transition.
            nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                d.x0 = d.x;
                d.y0 = d.y;
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course I am still interested. I accepted the answer NOT because it worked on my computer BUT because you thankfully trying hardly to help me and I appreciate that. So, now, really I started getting so crazy! Why it is not working on my end????? I just copied the exact same code and run it BUT it is not working!!!! SO weird!!! Not sure why!!! Other html scripts work normally, except this one!!!

Comment: Do you have any json dependencies in the same directory of this html file? Do you just run it as html by itself and it should work? Is there something else that I need to check on my computer to make this html script run?

Comment: My pleasure @dominican324. It'd be very helpful if you could give me a little detail on how you solved it :)

Comment: None of the scripts I was importing were found through the URL provided. I had to prefix all of them with https and thats how it worked. Example: h t t p s : / / cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.3.1/d3.min.js

Comment: Great, thanks for the insight. I'm glad you solved your problem!

Comment: Thanks for you, Parzival. Couldn't make it without your help :)

Comment: Would you please take a look at my new posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65927139/my-html-script-has-a-lot-of-href-urls-and-is-causing-my-page-to-slow-down-how-t?noredirect=1#comment116564843_65927139

Comment: Hi, I just reviewed your new question. Sorry that I'm not an expert in storing many images. However, if you were to consider doing an image search engine or a social media that stores billions of images like Facebook, I would consider storing images in a file system and image paths in a database. Check out this post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446358/storing-a-large-number-of-images

Comment: In terms of loading many images at the same time to a webpage, consider resizing, compressing(jpeg), removing metadata, and using CDN for serving images. Learn more about CDN here: https://web.dev/image-cdns/

Answer (score 1):

I just compared your code and the sample code you provided on bl.ocks.org

Your issue is that you moved the data in `flare.json` into the javascript section, causing `d3.json` not to find any data. Try removing this large json portion in javascript and add a file called `flare.json` in the same directory as your HTML file, and copy the JSON there.

The directory tree:

```
├── index.html
├── flare.json
```

I modified the original code since there were several HTML issues. Here is the modified HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <style>
        .node {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    
        .node circle {
            fill: #fff;
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
    
        .found {
            fill: #ff4136;
            stroke: #ff4136;
        }
        .node text {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }
    
        .link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #ccc;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
        /*Just to ensure the select2 box is "glued" to the top*/
        .search {
          width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="search"></div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- This will be attached to select2, only static element on the page -->
    
    
    <!-- Main -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        //basically a way to get the path to an object
        function searchTree(obj,search,path){
            if(obj.name === search){ //if search is found return, add the object to the path and return it
                path.push(obj);
                return path;
            }
            else if(obj.children || obj._children){ //if children are collapsed d3 object will have them instantiated as _children
                var children = (obj.children) ? obj.children : obj._children;
                for(var i=0;i<children.length;i++){
                    path.push(obj);// we assume this path is the right one
                    var found = searchTree(children[i],search,path);
                    if(found){// we were right, this should return the bubbled-up path from the first if statement
                        return found;
                    }
                    else{//we were wrong, remove this parent from the path and continue iterating
                        path.pop();
                    }
                }
            }
            else{//not the right object, return false so it will continue to iterate in the loop
                return false;
            }
        }
    
        function extract_select2_data(node,leaves,index){
                if (node.children){
                    for(var i = 0;i<node.children.length;i++){
                        index = extract_select2_data(node.children[i],leaves,index)[0];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    leaves.push({id:++index,text:node.name});
                }
                return [index,leaves];
        }
    
        var div = d3.select("body")
            .append("div") // declare the tooltip div
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0);
    
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
            width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
            height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
        var i = 0,
            duration = 750,
            root,
            select2_data;
    
        var diameter = 960;
    
        var tree = d3.layout.tree()
            .size([height, width]);
    
        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
    
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
        //recursively collapse children
        function collapse(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d._children.forEach(collapse);
                d.children = null;
            }
        }
    
        // Toggle children on click.
        function click(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            }
            else{
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
            update(d);
        }
    
        function openPaths(paths){
            for(var i =0;i<paths.length;i++){
                if(paths[i].id !== "1"){//i.e. not root
                    paths[i].class = 'found';
                    if(paths[i]._children){ //if children are hidden: open them, otherwise: don't do anything
                        paths[i].children = paths[i]._children;
                        paths[i]._children = null;
                    }
                    update(paths[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    
        d3.json("flare.json", function(error,values){
            root = values;
            select2_data = extract_select2_data(values,[],0)[1];//I know, not the prettiest...
            root.x0 = height / 2;
            root.y0 = 0;
            root.children.forEach(collapse);
            update(root);
            //init search box
            $("#search").select2({
                data: select2_data,
                containerCssClass: "search"
            });
        });
        //attach search box listener
        $("#search").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
            var paths = searchTree(root,e.object.text,[]);
            if(typeof(paths) !== "undefined"){
                openPaths(paths);
            }
            else{
                alert(e.object.text+" not found!");
            }
        })
    
        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");
    
        function update(source) {
            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
            links = tree.links(nodes);
    
            // Normalize for fixed-depth.
            nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });
    
            // Update the nodesâ€¦
            var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
    
            // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
            .on("click", click);
    
            nodeEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 1e-6)
            .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
    
            nodeEnter.append("text")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
                .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
    
            // Transition nodes to their new position.
            var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });
    
            nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                .attr("r", 4.5)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    if(d.class === "found"){
                        return "#ff4136"; //red
                    }
                    else if(d._children){
                        return "lightsteelblue";
                    }
                    else{
                        return "#fff";
                    }
                })
                .style("stroke", function(d) {
                    if(d.class === "found"){
                        return "#ff4136"; //red
                    }
            });
    
            nodeUpdate.select("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);
    
            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
                .remove();
    
            nodeExit.select("circle")
                .attr("r", 1e-6);
    
            nodeExit.select("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
    
            // Update the linksâ€¦
            var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });
    
            // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
            link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                });
    
            // Transition links to their new position.
            link.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("d", diagonal)
                .style("stroke",function(d){
                    if(d.target.class==="found"){
                        return "#ff4136";
                    }
                });
    
            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            link.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                })
                .remove();
    
            // Stash the old positions for transition.
            nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                d.x0 = d.x;
                d.y0 = d.y;
              });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `flare.json` file

```json
{"name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "animate",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
    {
     "name": "interpolate",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
      {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
      {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
      {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
      {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
      {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "data",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "converters",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
      {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
      {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
      {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
      {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
    {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
    {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
    {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
    {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
    {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "display",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
    {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
    {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
    {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "flex",
   "children": [
    {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "physics",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
    {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
    {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
    {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
    {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
    {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
    {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
    {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "query",
   "children": [
    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
    {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
    {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
    {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
    {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
    {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
    {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
    {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
    {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
    {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
    {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
    {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
    {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
    {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
    {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
    {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
    {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
    {
     "name": "methods",
     "children": [
      {"name": "add", "size": 593},
      {"name": "and", "size": 330},
      {"name": "average", "size": 287},
      {"name": "count", "size": 277},
      {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
      {"name": "div", "size": 595},
      {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
      {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
      {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
      {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
      {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
      {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
      {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
      {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
      {"name": "max", "size": 283},
      {"name": "min", "size": 283},
      {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
      {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
      {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
      {"name": "not", "size": 386},
      {"name": "or", "size": 323},
      {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
      {"name": "range", "size": 772},
      {"name": "select", "size": 296},
      {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
      {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
      {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
      {"name": "update", "size": 307},
      {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
      {"name": "where", "size": 299},
      {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
      {"name": "_", "size": 264}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
    {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
    {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
    {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
    {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
    {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
    {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
    {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
    {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
    {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "scale",
   "children": [
    {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
    {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
    {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
    {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
    {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
    {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
    {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
    {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
    {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
    {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "util",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
    {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
    {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
    {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
    {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
    {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
    {
     "name": "heap",
     "children": [
      {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
      {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
    {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
    {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
    {
     "name": "math",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
      {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
      {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
    {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
    {
     "name": "palette",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
      {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
      {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
      {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
    {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
    {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
    {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
    {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "vis",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "axis",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
      {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
      {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
      {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
      {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "controls",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
      {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
      {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
      {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
      {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
      {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
      {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
      {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
      {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
      {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
      {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "data",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
      {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
      {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
      {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
      {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
      {
       "name": "render",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
      {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
      {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "events",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "legend",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
      {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
      {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "operator",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "distortion",
       "children": [
        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "encoder",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "filter",
       "children": [
        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
      {
       "name": "label",
       "children": [
        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "layout",
       "children": [
        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
      {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
      {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
      {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
      {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable insights. I created two separate files in one place as you directed, but still doesn't work!

Comment: Hi, sorry there was a styling issue with Stack Overflow so for some reason the opening curly braces in flare.json did not show up. Try copying flare.json again and it should work now!

Comment: Can you check please your console and see if there's an error message? It works on my end.

Comment: I am using different browsers and no error message returned.... just giving it up! Thanks for your efforts though.