# My html script has a LOT of href urls and is causing my page to slow down, how to solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So, really I am a beginner on scripting and I did multiple hours research to find a solution but couldn't figure it out.

I have a "image search jquery script. It runs normal when I have everything embedded in one single html code. Yet, things started to get difficult (slow browser, sluggish browser response, slowing down the computer...) when the number of images links reached around 2000!

The thing that I thought would solve the issue is to split my html code into separate pieces (html, js, css...).

And that is where I got stuck!

Kindly, I need your help on how to save these href urls or links in a separate file then call them individually from the html.

Here is what I did (again, I am not an expert):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Search for Image</h2>

    <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Search!">
    <input type="text" id="myinput" name="search" placeholder="search..." style="width:50; height: 20px; border-radius: 4px; font-size: 18px;"><br><br>

    <a href="div_section.html"></a>
    <script src="javascripts/main.js"></script> 
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mybutton").on('click', function() {
        var mysrchbox = $("#myinput").val();
        mysrchbox = mysrchbox.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
        var val = $.trim(mysrchbox);
        if (val === "") {
            $('#none').show();
            $('img').hide();
        } else {
            val = val.split(" ").join("\\ ");
            if ( $("img[alt*=" + val + " i]").attr('alt') === undefined ) {
                $('#none').show();
                $('img').hide();
            } else {
                $('#none').hide();
                $('img').hide();
                $("img[alt*=" + val + " i]").show();
                $("img[alt*=" + val + " i]").css('display', 'inline-flex');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**styling.css**

```
body {
    background: white !important;
}

#images {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-basis: 33.3%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#images img {
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    display: none;
    object-fit: contain;
    height: max-content;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

#images img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**div_section.html**

```
<div id="images"><span id="none" hidden="true">no result related for your search.</span>
  <a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\user\dir-to-image\bitcoin-clipart-transparent-png.png" alt="eBitcoin" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\user\dir-to-image\cryptocurrency-wallet-ethereum-dogecoin-hd-png-download.png" alt="Ethereum" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\user\dir-to-image\/Ripple-Logo.png" alt="Ripple" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\user\dir-to-image\/tsmzy49d4adz.jpg" alt="eBitcoin Cash" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\user\dir-to-image\cardano-logo-png-5-Transparent-Images.jpg" alt="eCardano" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\user\dir-to-image\DJkf7M4VYAAgt8V.png" alt="NEM" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\user\dir-to-image\litecoin-logo.png" alt="LiteCoin" width=130></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\user\dir-to-image\1486429998.png" alt="Stellar Lumens" width=130></a>

</div>
```

Comment: This might seem difficult and I don't know all the specifics of your needs, but I would consider having a list of image names and sources, then after search has been made you could choose to dynamically load the top search images using js. does that make any sense?

Comment: For example (on init) `var list = {"cat": "cat.png", "dog": "dog.jpeg" /*...etc*/}` and (search button) `onclick = "search()"` and then loop through entries of list to find top matches then displaying dynamically created `Image` objects of the top matched sources

Comment: @OtherMe, thank you for your suggestion but honestly I don't know how to implement your approach!

Comment: Your welcome, the answer below is simpler and if it works I believe it would be a better solution so definitely try it first.

Comment: @OtherMe, I tried it and it is slower unfortunately! It takes memory of my machine more than my original code does. The original code takes around 1GB and the suggested code takes more than 1.5GB.

Comment: @karim79 salam alaykum

Answer (score 0):

- Add `loading="lazy"` to all `<img>` tags
- If possible, download the images, compress them with an online tool, save them in your project folder and change the `src` attribute to target the local images
- If possible remove the jQuery and replace your code with the following

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#mybutton')
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img')
const none = document.querySelector('#none')
imgs.forEach(img => img.style.display = 'none')

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const mysrchbox = document.querySelector('#myinput').value
  const val = mysrchbox.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, '').trim().toLowerCase()
  imgs.forEach(img => img.setAttribute('hidden', 'true'))
  if (val === '') {
    imgs.forEach(img => img.style.display = 'none')
    none.removeAttribute('hidden')
  } else {
    let showImgs = []
    imgs.forEach(img => {
      if (img.getAttribute('alt').toLowerCase().startsWith(val)) showImgs.push(img)
    })
    if (showImgs.length !== 0) {
      none.setAttribute('hidden', 'true')
      imgs.forEach(img => img.style.display = 'none')
      showImgs.forEach(img => img.style.display = 'inline-flex')
    } else {
      imgs.forEach(img => img.style.display = 'none')
      none.removeAttribute('hidden')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: white !important;
}

#images {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-basis: 33.3%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#images img {
background: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  object-fit: contain;
  height: max-content;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

#images img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<head>
  <script src="javascripts/main.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Search for Image</h2>

  <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Search!">
  <input type="text" id="myinput" name="search" placeholder="search..."
    style="width:50; height: 20px; border-radius: 4px; font-size: 18px;"><br><br>

  <div id="images"><span id="none" hidden="true">no result related for your search.</span>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/108-1082674_bitcoin-png-bitcoin-clipart-transparent-png.png" loading="lazy" alt="eBitcoin" width=130></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://png.pngitem.com/pimgs/s/692-6924771_blockchain-cryptocurrency-wallet-ethereum-dogecoin-hd-png-download.png" loading="lazy" alt="Ethereum" width=130></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ripple-Logo.png" loading="lazy" alt="Ripple" width=130></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://i.redd.it/tsmzy49d4adz.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="eBitcoin Cash" width=130></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://freepikpsd.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/cardano-logo-png-5-Transparent-Images.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="eCardano" width=130></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DJkf7M4VYAAgt8V.png" loading="lazy" alt="NEM" width=130></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://bitkee.com/icons/litecoin-logo.png" loading="lazy" alt="LiteCoin" width=130></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://bittrust.s3.amazonaws.com/1486429998.png" loading="lazy" alt="Stellar Lumens" width=130></a>
  
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I apologize for the confusion here, I just corrected my images paths/urls. In fact, I already have my images on my PC locally, but since they are around ~2000 images, this means I will have to use 2000 lines for links/srcs. What I was thinking is if there is a better approach to put these links outside the html in a separate file. Running my HTML file altogether with these URLs is slowing down the browser as well as my PC.

Comment: Not really, you will have to implement lazy-loading into the images, either with the loading attribute or the Intersection Observer API. That will greatly reduce the amount of data being downloaded at once and should improve performance. Removing jQuery can also help a bit.